# NSURLConnection POSTing JSON data to ASP.Net WebAPI not returning a response

Tags: objective-c, ios, asp.net-web-api

I am currently posting json data using an asynchronous NSURLConnection to a ASP.Net WebAPI resource.  The connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite: is being called, and the correct amount of data is being written.  But the connection:didReceiveResponse:, connection:didReceiveData: or connectionDidFinishLoading: are not being called, but eventually it gives up, and the connection is lost.

I am setting up the connection as follows:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL URLWithString:[Common baseUrl]] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"api/iCat/wishlists/upload"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.f];
NSString *jsonString = [self generateStrippedJsonForWishlist:wishlist];
NSData *requestData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];
```

And initiating the connection with:

```
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Eventually the request will time out with a "The network connection was lost" error message.  To me it seems like the app is never completely finished writing the body of the message.

From the api side, the method is never actually being called (break point is not being hit).  But if I send the request with no body, then it does.

I have tested the same call using curl, and it is working as expected:

```
curl -v -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"CreatedBy":"iPad Simulator","ContactName":"Ddd","ContactEmail":"ddd","Products":[{"ProductId":117,"ProductName":"Internal doors - deco","Specification":""}]}' http://SCMOBILE02:1861/api/iCat/wishlists/upload
```

Comment: can you post your methods that are not working?

Comment: Is requestData nil? What is in jsonString?

Comment: In this example the json string is: {"CreatedBy":"iPad Simulator","ContactName": "Sss","ContactEmail": "sss","Products": [{"ProductId": 117,"ProductName": "Internal doors - deco","Specification": ""}]}

Comment: no, requestData is not nil.  As I mentioned, the connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite: is returning that the entire body has been written to the server.  None of the other delegate methods are being called, and the server method is not being triggered

Comment: Any chance you could use fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to capture the request header and message being sent to your server? Well worth comparing to the CURL request that works. It would probably help others diagnose the issue if you also posted that to your question.

Comment: I have setup fiddler as a reverse proxy (thanks Mark for that tip) and surprisingly the request then works as expected.  All methods are sending almost identical data (ignoring User-Agent and order).  I then go back to the original port, and the iOS POST still fails/hangs.  So maybe it is something to do with my development setup?  iOS app (simulator) -> IISExpress in Win7 Parallels.  note: curl is running from OSX.

Comment: Well my confusion continues.  I have created a basic ASP.Net WebApi project to post some data to, and a simple iOS app to post the data up.  When using Fiddler as a reverse proxy, all works fine, but talking directly to the API from the iOS app fails.  Surprisingly I have also used a OSX app (GraphicalHttpClient) and it also fails directly, curl still works.

Comment: I believe it has to be something with my Parrallels setup, but only from what appears to be objective-c based applications.  I have just setup 2 x Win2k8 servers and deployed the test site to them, and they work 100%.  I think the only solution during development is to have fiddler running all of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try library https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking while posting json data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code below ?

```
-(void) post
{
    NSString * a = @"{company_name : \"com\"}";
    NSString * URL = @"yourUrl";

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",a];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:20.0];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}
```

In your web api you should have the following class and post method like below

```
        public class company 
        {
            public string company_name { get; set; }


        }


       // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]company value)
        {
            var t = value;
        }
```